# Multicol cheatsheet format

Tags: multicol

I currently have the following template for a cheatsheet:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,subfigure,color,verbatim}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{savetrees}

% Begin the actual document content here.
\begin{document}
\begin{tiny}
\begin{multicols}{3}

\section*{Section I}
This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I. This is section I.
\begin{align}
    x^2 + y^2 = 2
\end{align}


\end{multicols}
\end{tiny}
\end{document}
```

which results in the following: [image]

The content spreads itself out over the three columns, but I want it to fill up one column before going to the next. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the environment as follows:

```
\begin{multicols*}
\tiny
<your content>
\end{multicols*}
```

[image]

I would also recommend using the switch `\tiny` instead of `\begin{tiny}....\end{tiny}`

Also, using `\tiny` is going to produce a substandard appearance in the fonts.  I would modify the page geometry and then using the `graphicx` package scale the produced image down.

*Using `graphicx` package*

Suppose you that you'll be using `letter`: so you've got and `8.5x11` sheet of paper.  Suppose that you'll be using `0.25in` margins.  Then the dimensions of the area you want to print to are `8x10.5`.  If scaling by `1/2`, then the dimensions of the printable area on the new page should be `16x21`.  You'll want a little bit of buffer around the edge:  so let's make the page dimensions `16.25x21.25` with a margin of `0.125in`.

Here's the enlarged version of your cheatsheet.  Save this in a file called `onepage.tex`.  You can use any compilation method of your choice for this file.

```
\documentclass{article}
%% paper dimensions increased approximately two-fold of printable area
\usepackage[margin=0.125in,paperwidth=16.25in,paperheight=21.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,subfigure,color,verbatim}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{savetrees}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}

\section*{Section I}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{align}
    x^2 + y^2 = 2
\end{align}
\lipsum[3-40]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Now, the cheatsheet itself will be set up as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{unit=0.25in}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{pspicture}(-16,-21)(16,21)
\makeatletter
\put(0,0){%
  \makebox(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{onepage}}}%
\makeatother
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Here I've reset the `psunit` to calculate the center of the page and then created a `pspicture` to fill the page with center at `(0,0)`.  The `\makebox(0,0)` centers the imported graphic at its physical center.  This elimates guess work about how to get the imported image to look properly centered on the page.

Since I'm using `pspicture` here, this file will have to be compiled the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` route.

[image]

The remaining issue will be whether your printer has enough resolution.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that! By the way, a lot of this code is copied from other people's LaTeX source and I have no idea what it does except by the resulting PDF lol.

Comment: Cool it works!!